# Having an interactive shell experience but running everything through dash

Tags: command-line, prompt, fish, dash

So i'm starting to get addicted to POSIX standards and simplicity yet i hate not having autocomplete using the arrows to go through characters and i want a cool shell prompt.

so is there anyway that i could have something like fish or Zsh or even bash on the front end so i can have autocomplete, a nice and informative prompt, being able to go forward and backward on the command with arrows but when i press enter the command itself is ran by Dash instead of the interactive thing unless the script requires bash fish or etc in the shebang?

i just want to feel comfortable when typing the command the rest can be harsh and simple i'm using Konsole although i'm thinking to changing to a console prompt that allows Überzug(yes i'm aware that GUI's exist for a reason, its just for LF)also forgot although sh redirects to dash on konsole i told it to go for bash

Comment: You could try `rlwrap dash` but output can be strange after hitting enter (prompt handling + duplicated line).

Comment: @A.B i've though of just piping it throught dash ie "command" | dash but does it really work or is it just an ilusion

Comment: What difference does it make whether some external command is run by dash or some other shell?

Comment: @muru its considerably faster i guess

Comment: Not faster than your input speed

Comment: @muru yeah ok for tiny scripts of course it wouldnt matter but maybe running a way bigger script would compound over time, Although maybe its not worth it since rarely ever i run scripts that are that big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I might have misunderstood your question, because what you seem to be asking for is pretty much the way most everyone operates anyway.  We use an interactive shell for, well, interaction.  But we expect that scripts are often run by a different shell.

This typically "just works", since the *vast* majority of the scripts you will execute will include a shebang line.  That way the script itself can request the interpreter *closest* to the feature set it needs.  If it needs POSIX compatibility, it should specify either:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
```

That may be `dash` (on Debian/Ubuntu flavors), or it could be BusyBox's `ash` (on Alpine), or something else. It's up to the distribution itself to make `sh` point to the most POSIX compliant shell that it provides by default.  In the distant past, in some (most?) cases, [this was even `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/11810933).

In the rare event that someone leaves out the shebang, well, be suspicious of the rest of the code-quality for starters.  But running it isn't a problem -- Just `sh scriptname.sh`.

But no one expects you to actually operate interactively under today's basic shells interactively.  Personally, I use `fish`, which is the furthest of the ones you mentioned from any form of POSIX compliance.  But I can write my scripts in `fish` (preferably, since it has a much more modernized scripting language) or POSIX, if I need portability.  And it doesn't matter, since it's the shebang that handles that.

The one area where this isn't the case is for scripts that need to be *sourced*, since they change the environment of the current shell instance.  These do not get executed with the shebang-specified interpreter, but *are* executed by the interactive shell itself.  I rarely find this to be a problem myself, since most all of the software that I use provides a `fish` config file if needed.  But in those rare instances when you really do need to source a POSIX file, there are utilities such as [bass](https://github.com/edc/bass) and others to help you do this.

For `bash` and `zsh`, this isn't even a problem, since most all config files are written to a lowest-common-denominator that they can be sourced in the "close-enough-to-POSIX-to-not-matter" Zsh and bash.

Comment: thanks! so if i use "sudo ln -sfT dash /usr/bin/sh" on the /bin library does that mean that has long as a script has a sh shebang would it run on dash even if i have zsh as a shell prompt(i prefered it since its still has a bit of posix compliance so i don't have to learn a complete new thing)

Comment: Yes, as long as the `sh` shebang is there, executing it (but not *sourcing* it) will run it in dash, assuming dash is your `/usr/bin/sh`.  That said, I don't recommend *redefining* `/usr/bin/sh`.  It's probably already `dash`, but it's distribution dependent.